# Error: Failed to load config "plugin:@stylistic" to extend from

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I'm trying to follow this guide here:

https://eslint.style/packages/default

First I installed the package with command:

```
npm i -D @stylistic/eslint-plugin
```

In the guide it is using  `.eslintrc.js` but I have `.eslintrc.json` and I did my best to convert from .js syntax to .json syntax

Here's what I have in my `.eslintrc.json`

```
... 
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@stylistic"
      ]
...
```

In the EsLint console I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to load config "plugin:@stylistic" to extend from.
```

What I'm trying to achieve is use this `no-multiple-empty-lines`    from that plugin to disable having multiple empty lines in *.ts files.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it myself.
Basically, you are supposed to provide a *config* when adding an element to the `extends` array.

As of 17/03/2024, the `@stylistic` plugin provides [several configs](https://github.com/eslint-stylistic/eslint-stylistic/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/configs/index.ts), so using one of them is as simple as changing your config to:

```json
"extends": [
  "plugin:@stylistic/recommended-extends"
]
```